# Spark scala - update/add new column in Json object and update with new dataframe value

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, struct

I want to update an array of objects within an existing `json` object with the content from another `json` object.

Initial object:

```
{
    "user": "gT35Hhhre9m",
    "date": "2016-01-29",
    "status": "OK",
    "reason": "some reason",
    "content": [
        {
            "foo": 123,
            "bar": "val1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Supplementary object:

```
{
    "id": "gT35Hhhre9m"
}
```

Post-merge object structure:

```
{
    "user": "gT35Hhhre9m",
    "date": "2016-01-29",
    "status": "OK",
    "reason": "some reason",
    "content": [{
        "foo": 123,
        "bar": "val1"
        "id": "gT35Hhhre9m"
    }]
}
```

Comment: you can get that by join and some manipulation but we have to see what you've tried so far.

Comment: fixed wording and formatting

Answer (score 0):

1. Flatten the "Initial object" and treat Spark dataframes as columnar
   data similar to a SQL table.
2. Complete transformations
3. Convert back to Spark dataframes as JSON.

Not thinking dataframe as JSON is the trick.